# Rails has_many association with different condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In the User class, I have:

```
has_many :posts, foreign_key: "by_user_id"
```

This generates the following sql (when I call `user.posts`)

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" 
WHERE "posts"."by_user_id" = 2
```

How do I define an association that generates the following sql ?

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" 
WHERE "posts"."by_user_id" = 2 or "posts"."group_user_id" = 2
```

The Posts table contains both columns (`by_user_id` and `group_user_id`) and `group_user_id` is also an id of a User.

Comment: why not Post.where('by_user_id = ? or group_user_id = ?', 2, 2) ?

Comment: no, i still want to call `user.posts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a class method inside the User model:

```
def posts
  Post.where('by_user_id = ? or group_user_id = ?', id, id)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Post.where(by_user_id: 2, group_user_id: 2)
```

Is this what you are looking for?